# What's the proper way to upgrade gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Most resources online say that you update gradle by simply updating the distribution URL. This is the answer all over Stack Overflow and all over.
Codepath also just says that a url update is enough: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Getting-Started-with-Gradle#upgrading-gradle

I've seen scattered throughout a couple of answers that to upgrade gradle you need to run a gradle update script from the command line `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version x.x.x`.

I haven't been able to find documentation that says "This is how you update gradle". On gradles website you can see, "This is how you add the gradle wrapper". I guess I'm not sure what is enough, and I feel like a lot of people are doing it the wrong way, and maybe are not benefiting from performance and speed increases in gradle.

Any canonical answer on this? Someone from the tools team want to comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is using the Gradle wrapper then Android Studio will automatically use it. The correct way to upgrade Gradle (via the wrapper) is to run

```
$ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version x.x.x --distribution-type all
```

The `--distribution-type` option is [supported since Gradle 3.1](https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/release-notes#the-distribution-type-can-be-selected-by-the-wrapper-task) and allows to use the `all` distribution instead of the default `bin` distribution to get proper IDE support for Gradle build files.

If you are unsure what the latest version `x.x.x` is, or you are setting up a project from scratch, you might be interested in my [gradle_bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/android/gradle_bootstrap.sh) helper script which is able to install / update the Gradle wrapper without having Gradle installed. Use it like:

```
$ gradle_bootstrap.sh all
```

Just updating the Gradle distribution URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as described in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle) is not enough in cases where `gradle-wrapper.jar` itself got updated.

Finally, if you do *not* use the wrapper yet, Android Studio will prompt to "Click 'OK' to use the Gradle wrapper, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of a local Gradle distribution", where the latter can point to the Gradle version that ships as part of its installation. At the example of Android Studio 2.2.3 that would be Gradle 2.14.1, which is a bit dated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there's any docs showing this answer or am I just blind?

Comment: This [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle) says "editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file" is the way to go. However, as described in my answer, I do not recommend this as the wrapper itself does not get updates that way.

Comment: "If your project is using the Gradle wrapper, and you have chosen to actually use the Gradle wrapper when importing the project into Android Studio for the first time" what would be the alternative? Don't you HAVE to use the gradle wrapper?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to. But I just realized that Android Studio, in contrast to IntelliJ IDEA on which it is based on, does not prompt you to use the wrapper if it's present. It simply uses it automatically, and if it's not present offers you to "Click 'OK' to use the Gradle wrapper, or 'Cancel' to manually set the path of a local Gradle distribution".

Comment: Okay. Because as far as I knew you always had to use the wrapper. 1. Using the wrapper and committing it to source control makes sense right? 2. If you set the path of a local gralde... is not that called the "wrapper" as well?

Comment: 1. Yes, committing the Gradle wrapper makes sense as then a) you don't depend on Gradle to be installed globally, and b) you use a fixed version of Gradle for all developers to guarantee a consistent build environment. 2. No, that"s not the wrapper, but the path to a "full" Gradle installation.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I never fully understood why people called it the gradle wrapper. So wrapper is the gradle that's IN your project while full gradle or just gradle is the one on your computer.

Comment: Basically yes. I'd phrase it like: The Gradle wrapper is an "installer" to bootstrap a full Gradle installation. The first time you run the wrapper it will download the specified full Gradle distribution. Succeeding calls to the wrapper will then just work as a "proxy" and forward all calls to the previously installed full Gradle distribution.